# Proof of proficiency in mathematics

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

Apologise if this question isn't relevant to this forum, I tried my best to look for similar questions but couldn't find one.

I am a computer science major enrolled in a not-so-renowned university in India.

I am in my pre-final year and have taken four math courses. While I did well in the first two (got an O grade i.e the highest grade possible), due to some personal problems, I got a D and a C in the next two courses. Unfortunately, my university does not have a provision to retake the courses.

My eventual plan is to apply for grad school in fields such as machine learning where they require a strong math background.

My question is: how can I *show* that I know the required math for the courses beyond my uni courses?

One way I thought was of doing MOOCs on the subjects and uploading my solutions to them somewhere? But the general consensus which I found here was that MOOCs don't hold much value when it comes to showing proficiency in a subject.

What are some other ways in which I can demonstrate my proficiency in the subject?

Thank you.

EDIT: The courses where I fared poorly included the following topics (since it's an engineering course, we don't have specific courses like Linear Algebra or Statistics - we instead learn an overview of mixture of a few math subjects each semester) - Fourier Analysis, Laplace Transform, Vector Algebra, Complex Variable and Mapping, Z-transform, Complex Integration, Matrices, Probability, Sampling Theory and Mathematical Programming.)

Comment: Are there other (optional) math courses that you could still take in your final year?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The relevant math courses are offered in the first two years of the 4 year degree and I am in my third year right now. I do have electives related to the program I want to specialise in, but other than that, no math courses.

Comment: What were the courses?

Comment: Edited to add more details.

Comment: Do any of your upcoming courses use these topics? Doing well in a course which makes use of vector algebra, for example, (even if it's not explicitly in the title) is a good way of showing you can do vector algebra.

Comment: Get a top reputation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Are you applying for Master or Ph.D programs? If you plan to apply for Ph.D programs, then you can consider applying a Master program and take a lot of math courses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way around crappy grades (other than explaining what happened in your personal statement). But as far as showing that you are competent in these subjects on a grad school application you could:

- Do a project which would clearly require knowledge of these topics.
- Take the Math Subject GRE and do well, assuming you're applying to programs which care about the subject GREs. The risk here is that what's covered on these exams isn't a perfect match for your integrated courses, but there is a lot of overlap.